# Generate V3 Token through API for premium CDN token authentication

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I am working on a solution where the CDN consumer has to request for a token along with some other parameters. I should be able to generate a token after some custom validation and return to the client along with token ttl. Client can use this token to access the CDN resources until the token is alive. I don't seem to find any sample code or any reference in the SDK to generate the token.

The workflow for manual operation is given here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth

I basically want to automate the token generation flow.

Comment: Is the any C# sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the solution. The sample source code is available here: https://github.com/VerizonDigital/ectoken